# Define a new dimension to one of the variables in netCDF file

Tags: netcdf, nco

I have a NetCDF file which include lots of variables (1d, 2d, 3d, and 4d). I want to add a new dimension to one of the 3d variables.

To make it more clear, suppose:

I have a 3d variable: A(d1, d2, d3)

I want to have 4d variable: A(d1, d2, d3, d4)

In fact, d4 is the new dimension which I would like to add to my variable. I do not have d4 in my file. I know it has just one value.

I would appreciate that if anyone guide me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [NCO](http://nco.sf.net):

ncap2 -s 'defdim("d4",737);A_new[$d1,$d2,$d3,$d4]=A' in.nc out.nc

Comment: Is there a way to maintain A's attributes in A_new?

Comment: A_new will have the same dimensions A. You might be using an older versiono of ncap2. Please update and try again.

Comment: I also find this removes the attributes of A in A_new, using NCO netCDF Operators version 4.9.2 "Delirium" built by brew on Catalina at Apr  6 2020 18:39:20
ncap2 version 4.9.2

Comment: Adrian, I tried (not too hard, though) and I cannot reproduce this behavior. Troubling that it fails for you and works for me. See output at http://dust.ess.uci.edu/tmp/adrian.txt